# Find a value such that the equation is true

Tags: javascript

I want to find a value of a numerical variable such that it makes the equation true. Example:

```
var a = random number;
var b = random number;

function (find var c such that a = b + c;) {

  console.log(c);

}
```

Is it possible to make the computer search for the answer of c? and not such that you undo the equation where c = a - b, but such that as it checks answers it gets closer to the value of c.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way (or at least no remotely simple way) to solve arbitrary algebraic equations with JavaScript.

Comment: This seems ambiguous.  From a mathematical perspective, there could be no answer, one answer, or even many answers depending on what domain you are searching through, and searching through an infinite domain doesn't seem feasible without using something along the lines of a computer algebra system.  Compare the questions: "find an integer c from [1,2,3,4] such that c^2=1", "find an integer c such that c^2=2", "find a positive real number c such that c^2=2", "find a real number c such that c^2=2"

Comment: If you have a *finite* domain that you are searching through available as an object or as an array, you can simply loop over that domain, checking each entry in the domain to see if it satisfies the condition, and keeping track of the list of which domain elements matched the condition.  If your domain is infinite or undefined, then I see no convenient way to approach this.

Comment: There are tons of SO questions about this (which almost all show lack of research, but that's maybe just my opinion), tons of articles on the internet, university courses, different approaches, approximations, you name it. Just because it is a generally interesting topic, plopping out a question like this (imho with probably less than five minutes of research, and in an underdefined manner), is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `z-z`, and then that's your number. But that's probably not what you are asking.